# consume REST service over https with self signed certificate in ionic 3 app

Tags: ssl, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3, self-signed

I'm trying to access an https resource `https://example.com/someservice` which uses a self signed certificate from an ionic 3 application, however I could not find anything that can help, the only thing I found is [use public key pinning with intel security API](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/604523)
but could know how to do this in ionic 3. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try the native http: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/